# Parse Date from Text String in a 3 column format

Tags: bash, shell, grep, sed

I am given an array of lines from a text file.  They look similar to this, and will always be structured like this:

```
            Full         Tue Aug 27 10:59:43 2019                 1
     Incremental         Tue Aug 27 11:16:41 2019                 1
     Incremental         Tue Aug 27 11:25:28 2019                 1
     Incremental         Tue Aug 27 13:37:29 2019                 1
```

Based on the above output, I do not believe these 3 columns qualify as fixed width... as you can see the date format can and will probably change based on the date string, as well, line one contains 4 characters in column one row one, while the same column contains 11 in row's 2 through end...

How can I parse the date from these lines, so my list is this instead:

```
Tue Aug 27 10:59:43 2019
Tue Aug 27 11:16:41 2019
Tue Aug 27 11:25:28 2019
Tue Aug 27 13:37:29 2019
```

I am sure `grep` or `sed` is probably the answer I need, I just don't know much about either.

Comment: You can use `cut` if fixed width is sound there.

Comment: @uprego  I don't think it will be fixed length based on the date format in the text it would vary based on the month, and day we're on

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment :/ but if you want to explain further, your question is a perfect canvas. :)

Comment: question editted with this: Based on the above output, I do not believe these 3 columns qualify as fixed width... as you can see the date format can and will probably change based on the date string, as well, line one contains 4 characters in column one, while the same column contains 11 in row's 2 through end...

Comment: I think I mighta got your point now. I hope someone who knows well the answers set can point to a relevant duplicate. If this gets tumbleweed just ping.

Comment: I mean not _get tumbleweed_ literally as I've heard it's been killed, but if it _becomes tumbleweed_ figuratively.

Comment: :) appreciate it.  i think if I split each line based on a space delimiter, I maye be able to piece together a "date string" based on the positional idx values in the resultant array...

Comment: as a for instance: `_d_string=${_temp_arr[1]}" "${_temp_arr[2]}" "${_temp_arr[3]}" "${_temp_arr[4]}" "${_temp_arr[5]}` displays just that date string.  however, it seems hackish...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if awk can help.

```
$ cat abc.txt
            Full         Tue Aug 27 10:59:43 2019                 1
     Incremental         Tue Aug 27 11:16:41 2019                 1
     Incremental         Tue Aug 27 11:25:28 2019                 1
     Incremental         Tue Aug 27 13:37:29 2019                 1
$ cat abc.txt  | awk '{print $2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6}'
Tue Aug 27 10:59:43 2019
Tue Aug 27 11:16:41 2019
Tue Aug 27 11:25:28 2019
Tue Aug 27 13:37:29 2019
```

Comment: Why print the 3rd field twice? Also, you don't need `cat` and you can separate the fields with comma (output field separator defaults to space), e.g. `awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' abc.txt`.

Comment: this consistently did the trick.  thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` and a regular expression to cut out the date of that.

Assuming your data is stored in the file *input*.

```
sed -e 's/^\s\+\S\+\s\+\(.*\S\)\s\+\S\+$/\1/g' input 
Tue Aug 27 10:59:43 2019
Tue Aug 27 11:16:41 2019
Tue Aug 27 11:25:28 2019
Tue Aug 27 13:37:29 2019
```

---

The first part `s/^\s\+\S\+\s\+` matches lines that begin with one or more whitespace character(s), followed by one or more non-whitespace character(s), followed again by one or more whitespace character(s). E.g.:

```
'            Full         '
'     Incremental         '
```

---

Let's look at the last part now `\s\+\S\+$`. This will match one or more non-whitespace character(s) at the end of the line, preceded by one or more whitespace character(s). E.g.:

```
'                 1'
```

---

The middle part `\(.*\S\)` is a matching group which can be referenced by `\1` and is called backreference. This one matches any character starting after the first match up to one non-whitespace character before the last match.
As already mentioned, `\1` is the backreference to the middle part and is printed out.

Comment: appreciated it.  I will test out when I'm back on it tomorrow.  thanks for your input :)